# Firestore not updating local database

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have an application that uses Firestore to save data to the server. I have configured offline persistence and get data using `addSnapshotListener()`. If I write something from my app, it is updated to server correctly, but on second device I can't see new data. If I get the document using `get()` data is updated but it is really slow. Is there anyway to update local database or get data from network if there is no changes to database?

Comment: I have the same problem. Customers claim that the data is not updating, however there's new data in the cloud. I use snapshot listeners. Have you found a solution? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54475739/cloud-firestore-offline-persistence-reliability-on-android

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of data-model in firestore you can use.

1. **collection**
2. **document**

you need to use snapshot Listener based on the data-model you are trying to fetch. For instance:

**for collection:**

```
db.collection("collectionPath")
            .addSnapshotListener(EventListener<QuerySnapshot> { snapshot, e ->
                if (snapshot != null) {
                    for (change in snapshot.documentChanges) {
                        //read document from the change -> change.document
                    }
                }
            })
```

**for document:**

```
db.document("documentPath")
            .addSnapshotListener(EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>{ snapshot, e ->
                if (snapshot != null) {
                    //read fields from document -> snapshot.getString("fieldName")
                }
            })
```

Comment: I do It like this, but if local persistance is enabled local database is not updated

Comment: as per the documentation, it says that the offline data enabled by default in firestore. what exactly are you doing for offline data?