# Cloud Firestore offline persistence reliability on Android

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Firebase's Cloud Firestore in an Android application for receiving product information. The Android client only reads from Firestore and never writes. Offline persistency is enabled. The product information is updated once a week.

I've received several reports of customers that claim that they still see outdated data even after I've changed the data in the cloud. These reports come in even days after the import so I guess their smartphone had an Internet connection in the meantime and it's not a connectivity issue.

The point is I could never reproduce this. I've checked the code a few times but don't see any error on my side. I'm reading from Firestore [once](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data) when the view is rendered. I do not use snapshot listeners.

I know this is all very vague so I'm just asking if anyone else made the same experience with Firestore on Android with offline persistency enabled?

Version of the Firestore library is 17.1.5.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had the same problem, however, just to help (maybe it's useful), few things to mention here, about how Cloud Firestore works:

1. First time the client-side SDK fetches, it fetches from the server, saves the results to the cache.
2. The second time you fetch, the first results will always come from the cache, until you fetch them from the server.
3. Until you fetch the new values from the server, they will keep coming from the cache.

You have specifications such as `Source.SERVER` or `Source.Cache`. If you can't really reproduce this, I might really think that this is something to do with the connection of your customers. However, for you to actually debug this and see the percentage of this happening, I would suggest you to (to actually see the impact and be more data-driven):

1. Add a timestamp object to your Firestore, whenever you update your information (as per week you say)
2. Add the same timestamp to [Firebase Remote Config](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config) for a key
3. Fetch these in your clients and compare, if not the same, and if the one from Remote Config is never, that means you hit the user group that has the described problem.

Just a dummy test for you to actually see the impact. From my current PoV, I can't help you more than this. However, I would also urge you to bump up your versioning on Cloud Firestore, currently, it's 21.3.0.

Comment: Hi rencsaridogan, thanks for your response. First of all, I'm already on version 21.3.0 of Firestore but some customers still report this behaviour. You say "The second time you fetch, the first results will always come from the cache, until you fetch them from the server". What do you mean by "until you fetch them from the server"? Do I have to explicitly request new data from the server? I thought the Firestore framework will handle this for me when the device is online, updating the local cache as required?

Comment: So, this is how the SDK works, what I mean is this scenario:

Comment: 1. Fetched from server, cached.
2. Queried.
3. Results immediately arrived from cache.
4. Fetched from server, cached, and served the new set of data.

This is on snapshots, if you do a GET, you can also specify which source you want to use custom on the GET itself (SERVER or not).

So, to sum it up, what I tell is exactly what Firebase handles internally, that's why I told you to do a test to determine the impact and pinpoint your issue, because it's very vague as the way is presented now, without some data to prove.